# When I create a new viewController in one of my folder, the controller contained in a folder named: ctive-C

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

When I create a new `viewController` in one of my folder `A`, the controller not shown in the left list tree. More than the folder `A` contains a new folder named `ctive-C` in which the new `.h` and `.m` files placed .

Xcode version: `8.3.2`

Comment: removed helpme and thank you

Comment: Do you mean just remove the folder?

Comment: if you got the solution please share with us

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fix it by `reinstall`ing the Xcode